# Pythagorean theorem in Riemann metrics of non constant curvature

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I already asked the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4701212/pythagorean-theorem-in-riemann-metrics-of-non-constant-curvature), but received no answer. I was reading this interesting article by Givental

[Givental, Alexander. "The Pythagorean theorem: What is it about?" Amer. Math. Monthly 113 (2006), no. 3, 261–265](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27641894)

And my attention was caught by this passage:

"*This explains why the Pythagorean theorem is a genuinely Euclidean phenomenon (and not only in the
historical sense of the word): among all Riemannian metrics of constant curvature only the Euclidean one admits nontrivial conformal isometries.*"

So that's the question: there exist Riemannian metrics of non constant curvature admitting nontrivial conformal isometries? If so, the Pythagorean theorem holds on them?

[image]

Comment: I don't have a proof, but my belief is that whether the Pythagorean Theorem holds is equivalent to whether there is any nontrivial holonomy when a tangent vector is parallel translated around a closed curve. If so, this would prove that the Pythagorean holds if and only if the metric is flat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think (see (??) below) there is no connected **complete** Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ which is not flat and such that there is an isometry $f:(M,g)\to(M,\lambda^2g)$, where $\lambda\neq0,1$. I will assume $\lambda>1$, if not take the inverse function.

If there were such an isometry $f$, then for any $p\in M$ the sequence $f^np$ would be Cauchy in the Riemannian distance $d_g$, because $d_g(f^n(p),f^{n+1}(p))=\frac{d_g(p,f(p))}{\lambda^n}$.

As $M$ is not flat there are non zero sectional curvatures so we can find a small geodesic triangle $T$ with sum of angles $S\neq\pi$. The sum of angles $S_n$ of the triangle $T_n=f^n(T)$ is just $S_n=S$, because $f$ is conformal. However, if $M$ is complete, then the triangles $T_n$ converge to some point $q$. But $g$-sectional curvatures are bounded in a small neighborhood of $q$, and the diameters of $T_n$ converge to $0$, so $S_n$ should converge to $\pi$, (?? my previous argument had a fallacy I think, I was assuming that a subsurface was totally geodesic. The fact that the sums of angles of geodesic triangles convergent to a fixed point must converge to $\pi$ is probably still true. By the CAT inequalities, using that sectional curvatures are bounded near $q$, one can see that $S_n$ cannot converge to anything above $\pi$, I don't know if there is a similar result to see that they cannot stay below some constant $<\pi$ either).

In the **non-complete** case there are counterexamples: consider a bump function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ which is supported in the ball centered at $(1,0)$ and of radius $0.1$. Now consider the function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}2^nf\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)$.

Then the graph of $g$, as a Riemannian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$, is not flat, but it is invariant by the isometry $f:(\mathbb{R}^3,g)\to(\mathbb{R}^3,g/4);x\mapsto2x$ (where $g$ usual metric of $\mathbb{R}^3$).

In any case, the **usual Pythagorean theorem** with right triangles cannot always hold if there are non zero sectional curvatures: in the book "Metric spaces of non positive curvature", by Bridson and Haefliger, in the proof of theorem 1A.6, it is mentioned that if $M$ has sectional curvature $\kappa\in\mathbb{R}$ in some plane, then we can find small right triangles with squared sides $\varepsilon^2,\varepsilon^2,2\varepsilon^2-\frac{K}{6}\varepsilon^4+O(\varepsilon^5)$, thus the Pythagorean theorem does not hold.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I really appreciate that! So in the non-complete case is it possible to affirm that the Pythagorean theorem holds in $ M $ locally, and so that $ M $ is locally isometric to $ \mathbb{R^2} $?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by the Pythagorean theorem holding locally? Do you mean in the sense that every point has a nhood such that for every right geodesic triangle with lengths $a\geq b\geq c$ we have $a^2=b^2+c^2$?

Comment: Yeah, I mean that

Comment: And when do you say it should be possible to affirm that? Because in my non complete counterexample it need not hold.

Comment: I ask because I want to know if there is some kind of not flat Riemann manifold, where the Pythagora theorem holds. From your answer I understand that it needs to be non complete, but explicitly is there a non complete Riemann manifold where the Pythagora theorem holds? I guess so because Givental links the theorem to nontrivial conformal isometries

Comment: I see. So the new question is whether Pythagoras' theorem (the one with right triangles) holds in any non flat manifold. I am pretty sure it doesn't (again it will be enough to consider a subsurface with nonzero sectional curvature), I will write it in another answer when I can

Comment: Nope there was a mistake in my argument to prove that Pythagoras' theorem does not hold, specifically I can prove it manifolds with some positive sectional curvature but not in negative curvature manifolds. For the negative curvature case I would need something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4705988/807670) , if no one answers it I will also ask it in MO. Also, I noticed that in the question you also asked whether Pythagoras' theorem holds in manifolds with nontrivial conformal isometries, I hadn't noticed that and I didn't answer it so if you want you can unaccept my answer.